# How to set up XAMPP to use Windows PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, cmd, xampp

I was searching in [XAMPP's](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) for an option which allows me when i click the Shell button on the right instead of opening a command prompt (cmd) to open a Windows PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you're asking, but, is changing the default shell an option?  See this answer:

https://superuser.com/questions/608194/how-to-set-powershell-as-default-instead-of-cmd-exe

Comment: Yeah it's not exactly what i am searching for.. But thanks anyway. I guess there is just no way to do this with XAMPP.